# Convert JSON date date to Timestamp Field

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have source data in JSON column in snowflake and need to convert to timestamp field.

Source data:

```
[
  {
    "end_time_of_day_of_week": {
      "day_of_week": "TUESDAY",
      "time_of_day": {
        "hours": 23,
        "minutes": 59,
        "nanos": null,
        "seconds": 59
      }
    },
    "start_time_of_day_of_week": {
      "day_of_week": "TUESDAY",
      "time_of_day": {
        "hours": null,
        "minutes": null,
        "nanos": null,
        "seconds": null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "end_time_of_day_of_week": {
      "day_of_week": "WEDNESDAY",
      "time_of_day": {
        "hours": 23,
        "minutes": 59,
        "nanos": null,
        "seconds": 59
      }
    },
    "start_time_of_day_of_week": {
      "day_of_week": "WEDNESDAY",
      "time_of_day": {
        "hours": null,
        "minutes": null,
        "nanos": null,
        "seconds": null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "end_time_of_day_of_week": {
      "day_of_week": "THURSDAY",
      "time_of_day": {
        "hours": 23,
        "minutes": 59,
        "nanos": null,
        "seconds": 59
      }
    },
    "start_time_of_day_of_week": {
      "day_of_week": "THURSDAY",
      "time_of_day": {
        "hours": null,
        "minutes": null,
        "nanos": null,
        "seconds": null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "end_time_of_day_of_week": {
      "day_of_week": "SATURDAY",
      "time_of_day": {
        "hours": 23,
        "minutes": 59,
        "nanos": null,
        "seconds": 59
      }
    },
    "start_time_of_day_of_week": {
      "day_of_week": "SATURDAY",
      "time_of_day": {
        "hours": null,
        "minutes": null,
        "nanos": null,
        "seconds": null
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Target output 2 column with each days time (null will be replaced by zero):

```
|| start_time  ||  end_time ||
TUESDAY 00:00      TUESDAY 23:59
WEDNESDAY 00:00    WEDNESDAY 23:59
THURSDAY 00:00     THURSDAY 23:59    
SATURDAY 00:00     SATURDAY 23:59    
Tuesday 23:
```

Comment: This || start_time || end_time || TUESDAY 00:00 TUESDAY 23:59 ....... is your expected result?
How are you planning to send this JSON to the database? What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

So given the data is repeated, I trimmed it to two rows:

```
with data(json) as (
    select parse_json('[
  {
    "end_time_of_day_of_week": { 
      "day_of_week": "TUESDAY", "time_of_day": { "hours": 23, "minutes": 59, "nanos": null, "seconds": 59 }
    },
    "start_time_of_day_of_week": {
      "day_of_week": "TUESDAY", "time_of_day": { "hours": null, "minutes": null, "nanos": null, "seconds": null }
    }
  },
  {
    "end_time_of_day_of_week": {
      "day_of_week": "WEDNESDAY", "time_of_day": { "hours": 23, "minutes": 58, "nanos": null, "seconds": 59 }
    },
    "start_time_of_day_of_week": {
      "day_of_week": "WEDNESDAY", "time_of_day": { "hours": null, "minutes": null, "nanos": null, "seconds": null }
    }
  }
]')
)
```

so using FLATTEN to unroll the ARRAY, and then accessing the fields, you can use the values. I using LPAD to make things 2 characters wide, and ZEROIFNULL to handle the variant nulls.

```
select f.value:"start_time_of_day_of_week" as s
    ,f.value:"end_time_of_day_of_week" as e
    ,s:day_of_week as s_dow
    ,s:time_of_day as s_tod
    ,e:day_of_week as e_dow
    ,e:time_of_day as e_tod
    ,lpad(zeroifnull(s_tod:hours::int),2,0) as s_h
    ,lpad(zeroifnull(s_tod:minutes::int),2,0) as s_m
    ,zeroifnull(s_tod:seconds::int) as s_s
    ,zeroifnull(s_tod:nano::int) as s_n
    ,lpad(zeroifnull(e_tod:hours::int),2,0) as e_h
    ,lpad(zeroifnull(e_tod:minutes::int),2,0) as e_m
    ,zeroifnull(e_tod:seconds::int) as e_s
    ,zeroifnull(e_tod:nano::int) as e_n
    ,concat( s_dow, ' ', s_h, ':', s_m ) as start_time
    ,concat( e_dow, ' ', e_h, ':', e_m ) as end_time
from data as d
 ,table(flatten(input=>d.json)) f
```

gives:

| S | E | S_DOW | S_TOD | E_DOW | E_TOD | S_H | S_M | S_S | S_N | E_H | E_M | E_S | E_N | START_TIME | END_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| { "day_of_week": "TUESDAY", "time_of_day": { "hours": null, "minutes": null, "nanos": null, "seconds": null } } | { "day_of_week": "TUESDAY", "time_of_day": { "hours": 23, "minutes": 59, "nanos": null, "seconds": 59 } } | "TUESDAY" | { "hours": null, "minutes": null, "nanos": null, "seconds": null } | "TUESDAY" | { "hours": 23, "minutes": 59, "nanos": null, "seconds": 59 } | 00 | 00 | 0 | 0 | 23 | 59 | 59 | 0 | TUESDAY 00:00 | TUESDAY 23:59 |
| { "day_of_week": "WEDNESDAY", "time_of_day": { "hours": null, "minutes": null, "nanos": null, "seconds": null } } | { "day_of_week": "WEDNESDAY", "time_of_day": { "hours": 23, "minutes": 58, "nanos": null, "seconds": 59 } } | "WEDNESDAY" | { "hours": null, "minutes": null, "nanos": null, "seconds": null } | "WEDNESDAY" | { "hours": 23, "minutes": 58, "nanos": null, "seconds": 59 } | 00 | 00 | 0 | 0 | 23 | 58 | 59 | 0 | WEDNESDAY 00:00 | WEDNESDAY 23:58 |

which can be simplified to:

```
select 
    start_time
    ,end_time
from (
    select f.value:"start_time_of_day_of_week" as s
        ,f.value:"end_time_of_day_of_week" as e
        ,lpad(zeroifnull(s:time_of_day:hours::int),2,0) as s_h
        ,lpad(zeroifnull(s:time_of_day:minutes::int),2,0) as s_m
        ,lpad(zeroifnull(e:time_of_day:hours::int),2,0) as e_h
        ,lpad(zeroifnull(e:time_of_day:minutes::int),2,0) as e_m
        ,concat( s:day_of_week, ' ', s_h, ':', s_m ) as start_time
        ,concat( e:day_of_week, ' ', e_h, ':', e_m ) as end_time
    from data as d
     ,table(flatten(input=>d.json)) f
)
```

| START_TIME | END_TIME |
| --- | --- |
| TUESDAY 00:00 | TUESDAY 23:59 |
| WEDNESDAY 00:00 | WEDNESDAY 23:58 |

Comment: Please look at follow up question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73172004/find-working-days-based-on-weekly-or-monthly-schedule

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Snowflake `flatten` function to convert the JSON array to rows.

Note that your desired output is not really a timestamp. It's a string (varchar). If there were enough information to construct a timestamp, the SQL could do that and output it with a format string the way you have it. However, there's not enough information to create a timestamp so this shows how to make it a varchar formatted as your target output.

```
create or replace table T1(v variant);

insert into T1 select parse_json($$ >>> Paste your JSON here <<< $$);

select * from T1; -- Make sure your JSON is in the table correctly.

select * from T1, table(flatten(v)); -- Start the flattening and extraction with this.

select   VALUE:start_time_of_day_of_week.day_of_week::string || ' ' ||
            nvl(VALUE:start_time_of_day_of_week.time_of_day.hours::string, '00') || ':' ||
            nvl(VALUE:start_time_of_day_of_week.time_of_day.minutes::string, '00')
            as START_TIME
        ,VALUE:end_time_of_day_of_week.day_of_week::string || ' ' ||
            nvl(VALUE:end_time_of_day_of_week.time_of_day.hours::string, '00') || ':' ||
            nvl(VALUE:end_time_of_day_of_week.time_of_day.minutes::string, '00')
            as END_TIME
from T1, table(flatten(v));
```

Output:

| START_TIME | END_TIME |
| --- | --- |
| TUESDAY 00:00 | TUESDAY 23:59 |
| WEDNESDAY 00:00 | WEDNESDAY 23:59 |
| THURSDAY 00:00 | THURSDAY 23:59 |
| SATURDAY 00:00 | SATURDAY 23:59 |

Comment: Please look at follow up question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73172004/find-working-days-based-on-weekly-or-monthly-schedule